# Validação de campos no Client em ASP .NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, validação, lado-do-cliente

Estou precisando fazer validações de campos em um sistema tanto no lado do cliente como no lado do servidor, no lado do  servidor já consegui fazer, mas não encontrei nenhuma maneira de fazer validações no lado do cliente em asp.net MVC 4, alguém teria alguma coisa que possa me ajudar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A maneira de fazer validação em cliente no MVC4 é através do *jQuery.Validation*:

> http://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery.Validation

Os atributos colocados no seu *Model* são refletidos na *View*, e o *jQuery.Validation* é capaz de realizar esta validação na própria *View*.

Outras regras de validação podem ser colocadas na *View* através dos `htmlAttributes` do Helper @Html do Razor.

Comment: Valeu Cigano Morrison Mendez.
Vc teria um exemplo de código onde está sendo feito a validação ?
Ok. obrigado de novo pela ajuda.

Comment: @Everton A resposta está satisfatória? Então por favor marque a resposta como aceita (ícone com formato de V embaixo da pontuação da resposta) para o benefício da comunidade. Obrigado!

Comment: Esta sim @Cigano, vou marcar como aceita.