# Validação com Jquery em campos mvc

Tags: jquery, validação

Tenho uma View com alguns campos, preciso fazer uma validação para verificar se o campo está vazio quando o usuário clicar em um botão ex: salvar, pesquisei alguma funções em jQuery mais nenhuma atende o que preciso fazer, alguém conhece uma função jQuery que valida todos os campos de uma view sem precisar colocar o nome do campo ex:

```
Nome :{
        required : true
 }
```

gostaria de um exemplo onde a função fosse genérica, onde eu possa usar umas unica vez para vários campos.

Comment: Respondi isso aqui:

> http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11483/validacao-de-campos-no-client-em-asp-net-mvc-4/11485#11485

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O [jQuery Validate](https://github.com/DiegoLopesLima/Validate) pode te ajudar. É possível validar uma infinidade de coisas com muita facilidade. Se tiver alguma dificuldade pode deixar uma issue no repositório, sou o mantenedor e posso te ajudar com duvidas mais complexas.

Ela dispões de usos simples para validação como este:

```
<input type="text" data-required />
```

Ou:

```
<input type="text" data-pattern="^\d+$">
```

Answer (score 1):

Se você estiver usando o MVC do ASP .NET você pode decorar as suas propriedades com `[Required(Errormessage = "Campo obrigatório")]` que o próprio framework se encarrega disse, desde que o jquery validade esteja carregado no momento necessário para a validação.

na sua view você deve colocar `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(e => e.Propriedade)` para aparecer a mensagem vermelhinha.